# How do I tell if a string is an encrypted secure string or plain text in powershell?

Tags: powershell, securestring

Suppose I have a string:

```
"password"
```

And it may be in the form of an encrypted secure string converted to text. This secure string text may be decrypted via `ConvertFrom-SecureString` to recover the "password":

```
"1213132131....1232131" | ConvertFrom-SecureString |%{echo $_}
password
```

Is there any way to have powershell tell me whether the input string is already decrypted?

Or do I need to devise some other way to tell whether the input string is in plain text or encrypted as a secure string?

Comment: "And it may be in the form of an encrypted secure string converted to text." - how does that happen? Where does the input come from?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen "where does the input come from" -- no where. I am going and looking at a plain text file provided by a user and encoding it as the system user in a scheduled task.  If this is automated and recurring or even if it is only manually triggered by anyone w/ permission to trigger it, I need to ensure the string is not recursively-encoded.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I generally consider use case analysis in these questions to be out of scope. If I scope it so that it is easy, I'm probably skipping some huge contextualizing info-dump that you've got no need-to-know, and I've got no-time-to-write.  Suffice that I need to solve some problem in a particular way that I took care to simplify.

Comment: That's funny, cause the context you just provided is actually valuable :) If you're looking for heuristics for detecting one vs the other in source code, it might be better to discriminate on length and content - eg. if the string is >128 chars long and matches `^[a-f0-9]+$` then it's probably not a plaintext password

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that is exactly the kind of kludge I'd like to avoid, and I thought of already as insufficient.  Instead, the accepted answer is what is sufficient to leave alone as some forever process. The Powershell team would have signed their SecureStrings, and I have to find that logic.

Comment: And now you know why I asked :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yeah, I suppose I have experienced a few SO dogpiles on simple questions before. Your comment was fair, my bad.

Comment: No worries. FWIW I really do appreciate the attempt to narrow the scope, there was just a bunch of crucial info missing - like for example whether you'll be running your code under the same security context as it was originally created (a prerequisite for @mklement0's solution) - sorry if my deliberately broad questions came off as an attack :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat:

- Use of [`[securestring]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString) in new projects is *discouraged*, because it offers *very little* protection on *Unix*-like platforms and only *limited* protection on Windows. See [this .NET platform-compatibility recommendation](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406968/45375).

---

You can infer whether the string is encrypted or not based on whether applying [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring) to it succeeds or not:

```bash
# Sample input string, already decrypted.
$str = 'hello'

$isEncrypted = 
  $null -ne (
    $secureString = try { $str | ConvertTo-SecureString -ErrorAction Stop } 
                    catch { }
  )
```

If the string is encrypted - i.e. if it is the serialized form of a [`[securestring]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString) instance obtained with [`ConvertFrom-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring) - `$secureString` is assigned the deserialized form (i.e. a `[securestring]` instance).

Note that - by security-minded design - `ConvertTo-SecureString` only works if a given serialized-from-`[securestring]` input string was serialized *by the same user account*.